# 2-х секундное обращение к БД

Tags: setinterval, php, база-данных, get

Есть обращение к базе данных каждые 2 секунды.

```
setInterval(function() {
 $.get('...');
}, 2000);
```

Просто идёт получение информации. То есть 1 запрос. Хотел бы узнать, плохо это или нет(что-то запрашивать у БД каждые 2 секунды)?

Например многие предложат NodeJS. А представьте, если его нет. То как иначе?

Comment: если запрос выполняется 2 секунды, то это плохо. Если запрос выполняется 0.01 секунды, то 200 клиентов выдержит. Это конечно упрощенное объяснение, но для начала подойдет.

Comment: настоятельно рекомендую setTimeout.

Comment: @KoVadim, 2 секунды это плохо, а меньше 2-х секунд это хорошо. Как так?

Comment: А что Вас не устраивает?

Comment: @KoVadim неправильно понял, либо неправильно написал. Не запрос ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ 2 СЕУНДЫ, а ЧЕРЕЗ КАЖДЫЕ 2 СЕКУНДЫ.

Comment: я все правильно написал. Если время выполнения запроса умноженное на кол-во клиентов меньше интервала запроса - для пользователя хорошо. Если нет, то сервер не сможет обслужить клиентов. (конечно, нужно иметь небольшой запас).

О том, что запросы, которые долго выполняются, нагружают систему - я молчу. Это отдельная ситуация.

Comment: Теперь понял Вас! Ставлю + =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что открытая у клиента страничка обращается к серверному скрипту, который в свою очередь тащит значения из БД?

Если правильно - то сразу вопрос - сколько клиентов может сидеть одновременно?
Далее - используйте кэшь. Принцип: ваш скрипт непосредственно работает уже с подготовленными для отправки данными (храним их в файле). А вот сам файл перезаписывается после событий работы с таблицей (таблицами) - вставка, удаление, обновление

Comment: да уж лучше тогда memcache или redis вместо файлов

Comment: @MuFF, кэшировать ничего мне не нужно. Просто я получаю новые записи из БД каждые 2 сек.

Comment: простите а зачем вам получать данные из БД каждые 2 секунды? и почему вы не хотите получать теже подготовленные данные из файла?

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется что такой подход не правильный!
Лучше использовать для этого не запросы по таймеру, а кометы (***comet***, они же трекеры).
Когда устанавливается соединение с сервером (с тем же php-скриптом, это не существенно) и ожидается ответ. Ответ формирует сервер по каким-то событиям, - например кто-то написал в чат...
Примеров не дам - тут зависит от инструментов которыми вы пользуетесь... читый JS, jQuery, ExtSJ или ещё что-то...

Comment: Слишком ресурсоемко.
* написал текст выше и продолжил писать мгновенные сообщения так, как написано выше :D

Answer (score 4):

Давайте разберёмся. Вас интересует асинхронное обращение к серверу в реальном времени.
Такая модель работы веб-приложения называется **COMET**.
Со стороны клиента (браузера), существуют три способа реализации:

- polling
- long polling
- WebSocket

**WebSocket** - самая продвинутая на данный момент реализация, создающая с веб-сервером постоянное соединение (как бы поверх HTTP), поддерживается всеми современными браузерами (IE10 в том числе).
Ознакомительная статья:

[COMET](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet)

Первых две из этого списка, не требуют никаких  дополнительных "сложностей" в реализации со стороны сервера (обыкновенный Apache, без дополнительных extension-ов - привет виртуальному хостингу). Последний же, WebSocket, требует наличие неблокирующего демона (фреймворк [phpDaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) г-на Зорина, платформа [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) (Python) и др.)

[WebSockets — полноценный асинхронный веб](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/)

long polling строится на iframe-ах. Имеется неплохая реалиазция у г-на Котерова **"dklab_realplexor"**. Существует проект, работающий на это реализации:

[rutwit.ru](http://rutwit.ru/)

Ваш вариант, есть не что иное, как обыкновенный Polling - постоянные запросы через определённый интервал времени.

[[@KaZaца](/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0)](/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0) правильно отметил, необходимо использовать **setTimeout**, чтобы избежать висящих запросов, а именно:

```
function get()
{
    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'site.com',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){    
            setTimeout(get, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Конечно же, во всех случаях кэширование снимет приличную нагрузку с сервера, ибо данные будут браться из кэша (файлового, оперативной памяти), а не из БД.

Ответ [[@Ale_x](/users/3785/ale_x)](/users/3785/ale_x) немного ушёл в сторону методов кэширования, а именно, рассказал про событийный метод кэширвания. Но чтобы его реализовать, важно и нужно ещё разбираться в такой незамысловатой теме, как тегирование кэша. Так или иначе, эта уже другая история.

P.S. Весьма в понятной и забавной форме было рассказано про RealTime-ый веб. **Я плакал:)**

[**Разработка RealTime веб приложений**](http://addconf.ru/event.sdf/ru/add_2011/authors/NikitaGroschin/RealTimeDevelopment)

Comment: setTimeout('get()', 1000);

треш!

    setTimeout(get, 1000);

Comment: @exec Вы правы, с eval я погорячился

Answer (score 3):

Ничего плохого в этом нет, если БД справляется с нагрузкой.