# Выделение текста + $.get запрос

Tags: php, вконтакте

Интересует вопрос, как ВКонтакте реализовали авто-подгрузку новых записей на стене. Сижу я, например, на стене какого-то пользователя, кто-то другой написал на стену и тут же я увидел эту запись. Но проблема тут не в том, что я не знаю, как так сделать. Скорее знаю, но вот как сделать всё логично - не знаю.

Например:

```
<div id="wall"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
 $.get('/wall', function(data) {
  $('#wall').html(data);
 });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Так не круто. Я например выделил текст, а через 2 секунды обновилась вся область и выделение снялось естественно.

Пробывал другим путём. Подгружать записи через prepend():

```
$('#wall').prepend(data);
```

Тоже не вариант. А если из записей ниже, одна удалилась? То у всех она останется висеть, так как тупо сверху старых записей, добавились новые. Однако ВКонтакте это проверяется и запись удаляется мгновенно.

Хотелось узнать, вот как, как сделать всё нормально?

Comment: Почему бы не сделать так: вы посылаете на сервер тем же AJAX'ом время предыдущего обновления, а он вам назад -- список добавленных и удалённых с того момента записей? Всё просто.

Comment: Такие глобальные вещи лучше не на jQuery писать. Ember js или Backbone. Но суть остается та же, ajax запрос. Только в случае допустим с Ember, когда вы отправляете запрос, если появилось что то новое - создаете объект записи на стене и добавляете его в контроллер стены и он сразу появится на страничке. Ненадо танцевать с $('...').html() и т.п. он сам все сделает.имхо конечно же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На любой странице **ВКонтакте** все время висит **comet-запрос** к серверу.

На севере уже все и проверяется - `likes, add_new_post, delete_post, edit_post, new_messages` и т.д.

В случае **любого изменения** приходит ответ от сервера, в нем указан **тип** и **содержимое**. В зависимости от типа, JavaScript выполняет необходимые действия.

Советую поиграться с **Firebug** (расширение для *Firefox*) — много полезного узнаете.

Comment: @exec, вообщем over 9000 запросов? :)

Comment: На клиенте — один, на сервере — неизвестно.

Comment: @exec, в 1 запрос приходит вся информация чтоли? О редактировании, об удалении, о новой записи...

Comment: @ModaL, да.

Answer (score 2):

Ну... на самом деле не так чтобы уж мгновенно.

Лучше всего сделать стеком команд (что-то похожее отдает сервер, например в JSON'e):

- Добавить - ID, текст, картинка, ссылка;
- Добавить - ID-2, текст-2, картинка-2, ссылка-2;
- Удалить - ID;

Обновить тоже считается как команда добавить, но если такая запись существует, то обновляется.

Порядок вывода определяется по ИД или по временному штампу - как вам больше нравится.

Естественно такое лучше реализовывать long-pool - запросами, но при мелкой нагрузке пойдет и как вы написали.

И помните важное правило современной клиент-серверной разработки (в первую очередь веб) - на клиенте всегда есть лишние свободные ресурсы, а на сервере их всегда не хватает)

Comment: @SilverIce, то есть помимо получения записей(1 запрос), ещё нужно и удаление(2-ой запрос). Так?

Comment: Дались вам эти запросы) Нет. Все делается за один запрос - от сервера идет поток комманд, который разбирает клиент. Ну посмотрите же в конце концов как это сделано на том же VK.

Answer (score 2):

Вы таким выражением делаете множество "висяков". Вместо setInterval используйте setTimeout - об этом я писал Вам [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170836/php-2-%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B4)

```
<ul id="wall">
    <li id="msg_1">text</li>
    <li id="msg_2">text</li>
    <li id="msg_3">text</li>
    ...
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">   
var get = function () {
    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'site.com',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){    
            if (data) {

                /**
                 * Механизм удаления сообщений по их id
                 *
                 *  к примеру,
                 *  data = {1 : "text_1", 5 : "text_5"};
                 */ 
                $('li', '#wall').each(function(){
                    if (!data[/(\d+)/.exec(this.id)[1]]) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
            setTimeout(get, 1000);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Делаем запрос, получаем json с данными (id, текст сообщения...), к примеру, 10 последних. Далее, сравниваем - есть ли такие в DOM-е.

P.S. В контакте используется демон, возможно на [node-ах](http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/arkhitektura-vkontakte/).

Comment: @romeo, я использую timeOut) Просто быстро накалякал код и всё такое) То есть мне делать 2 запроса? 1 на получение записей, другой на удаление...?

Comment: @ModaL:
> То есть мне делать 2 запроса? 1 на получение записей, другой на удаление...?

Не совсем понял. Мы ведь говорим о реалтайме - Вы/он бездействуете, а некоторые блоки на странице обновляются. В этом случае, один запрос.

Допустим, пришёл запрос с json-объектом `{1 : "text_1", 5 : "text_5"};`, в нём сообщения с id 2 и 3 отсутствуют, но есть сообщение с id 5, которого нет в DOM-е.
Соответственно, 2 и 3 удаляем, 5-ое добавляем prepend-ом наверх (обработчик допишите сами). Анимация прилагается.
Вся область не обновляется и выделение снимается там, где блоки меняются.

-->

Comment: Любые Ваши действия (удаление/добавление сообщения на стене), это уже отдельный обработчик на клик.

Comment: @romeo, Вы не поняли. Вот смотрите. Подгрузились 20 сообщений. И 5 из них например от юзера romeo. Через 15 секунд romeo удалит 2 сообщения и в этой области, та, что подгрузилась, должны удалиться эти 2 сообщения.

Comment: @ModaL В этом случае два:

> 1 на получение записей, другой на удаление...

Причём получение записей, а вернее их отображение, можно реализовать аналогичным, как в случае с таймером способом, только по событию на клик.

P.S. Если бы не было постраничной/бесконечной навигации по сообщениям (к примеру, древовидные комменты на хабре), то можно было обойтись одним запросом на удаление.